# Are there native functions in VBA that handle serial communication similar to how the WSC32.DLL library does?

Tags: vba, ms-access, serial-port

I am trying to fix some ~20 year old VBA code in Access that uses Windows Standard Serial Communications created by MarshallSoft Computing. The 32 bit version stopped working. For implementation reasons, it would be a lot easier to use something native in VBA that doesn't require installing a new library. The code just uses a handful of the WSC32 functions and it would be great if there was a native library in VBA that paralleled those functions. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: There isn't. Stick with the MarshallSoft library, it is only $119 for an upgrade and about the best you can obtain.

Answer (score 0):

```
Declare Function CreateFile Lib "kernel32" Alias "CreateFileA" _
(ByVal lpFileName As String, ByVal dwDesiredAccess As Long, _
ByVal dwShareMode As Long, lpSecurityAttributes As Any, _
ByVal dwCreationDisposition As Long, ByVal dwFlagsAndAttributes As Long, _
ByVal hTemplateFile As Long) As Long
```

https://gist.github.com/heiswayi/f47dfd8dc38955322bef is the David M. Hitchner example.

A search for "Darren Richards Win32 comms API wrapper for VBA" gave me some links (on Google, not on Bing) to postings of the (shorter) Darren Richards example, but not an original source.

From http://www.hardandsoftware.net/NETCommOCX.htm, NETCOMM.OCX is a way of using the original MSCOMM32.OCX in VBA. I agree that using the native windows API is simpler, but if you want scripting as well, NETCOMM.OCX works in VBS.

You can just write to COM1, but the VBA file system object has trouble with binary, and with reading. And NTFS used the same syntax for creating forks in the file system that BASIC used for configuring COM ports. (And MS never implemented a pseudo file system fork to restore the missing function, which they could easily have done). As a consequence, you effectively either have to use a comm object or the Windows API.

Comment: References become rare. One source for the code from Darren Richards is https://www.herber.de/forum/archiv/716to720/719039_Frage_zu_Comportxls.html
Note: To use COM ports above 9 use "\\.\" as prefix, like "\\.\COM10". This syntax also works for port numbers below 10.